# Windows Server with Router in the same network, How to configure?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, router, dhcp

I have a network with Router that provide DHCP and DNS services to my network.

Also, i have a windows server 2008R2 in the same network.
I have +100 computers in the network, some must join the windows server and the other not.

How i should configure the Router and the windows server ?

can i have a windows server in the network and disable DHCP role in it and use dhcp from the router?

what about the DNS?

Thanks

Comment: If you'd like to talk to see how I might be of some service to you, feel free to contact me at the email address in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I'm a bit worried that someone managing 100+ computers would ask such a question here. Consider getting professional support.

To answer your question: You can configure them anyway you like, it really depends what you are trying to achieve. For example, if you are running an Active Directory on your Windows Server, then the computers within the AD will have to use it for DNS. But they might want to use the router address as gateway. Your other, non-AD computers could use the router address for both gateway and DNS. In addition to that, you could (and probably should) virtually partition your network using VLAN.

All in all, it really depends on your specific situation. Your question is way too broad to be answered fully here.

Comment: Thank you. i'm running an Active Directory on my Windows server. I want all the computers to take its network config (IP, DNS, Gateway..) from the Router. How to Active Directory clients about the DNS??